# A short research conference paper benefits

Tags: publications, conference

My paper has been accepted as a short research paper to be published as a conference paper. My question is, what is the best benefit for such a publication?

Edit:

It will be published at the IEEE conference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends heavily on what field you are in. In a small number of fields (mostly ones adjacent to theoretical computer science), the majority of new work is presented at conferences. Having a paper published at a good conference in those fields is just as good as having it published in a good journal. If you are in one of these fields, the thing you should find out is whether or not it’s been accepted for an “archival track,” “archival conference,” or similar (the word “archival” is very important). If the answer is yes, congrats! You have a full fledged research article that’s been reviewed by your peers and judged worthy of publication.

If your paper was accepted to a non-archival track or if you are not in one of those fields, then presenting your paper at the conference is primarily a learning experience. You are going to meet more established researchers in your field, and have a chance to present your research and ideas to them. This is a great experience to get (virtual) face-time with other people in your field and share ideas. Coming away from the conference, you’ll hopefully have received by praise and criticism, and can use what you learn to extend your conference paper into a full paper.

Comment: It will be published at the IEEE conference. I have no idea about the archival conference, all that I know will be presented as a short research paper.

Comment: If you do not know if the conference is archival, you should ask.

Comment: Three remarks here: 1. It's unclear whether the conference in this case is good; the fact that it's IEEE doesn't mean much in this respect. 2. A short paper is usually less valuable than a full-length paper (which might be comparable to a journal paper or even better). Still better than nothing for sure. 3. In many fields (especially those associated with IEEE) the word "archival" would not be mentioned explicitly.

Comment: @lighthouse I haven’t taken any position about the quality of the conference. You can scale the excitement of my remarks according to the prestige but I think what I said is true for any level of prestige (at least, non-predatory). A short paper may be less exciting than a “full length” paper, but anything we say about that would be highly speculative without further info so I opted to not do so. I’m not sure what fields you have in mind, but every computer science conference I have ever looked at clearly indicates if it’s archival or not using that word.